# Why my this java interest calculator program not working?

Tags: java, android, xml, calculator

I'm very new to android development. I designed and programmed a simple interest calculator. But it works to some extend only and if you try with large number it won't give correct answer and crashes the application. Here is my code

```
package com.example.minti;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InterestCalculator extends AppCompatActivity {


    float showResultData, totalAmtData;
    int firstValueData, secondValueData, thirdValueData;

    EditText firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue;
    Button findResult;
    TextView showResult, totalAmt;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_interest_calculator);

        firstValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.principleAmount);
        secondValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tenure);
        thirdValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.interestRate);
        findResult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.intCalculator);
        showResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intResult);
        totalAmt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalResult);


        findResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                firstValueData = Integer.parseInt(firstValue.getText().toString());
                secondValueData = Integer.parseInt(secondValue.getText().toString());
                thirdValueData = Integer.parseInt(thirdValue.getText().toString());

                showResultData = (firstValueData*secondValueData*thirdValueData)/36500;
                //totalAmtData = showResultData+firstValueData;
                showResult.setText(String.valueOf("Interest : " +showResultData));
                //totalAmt.setText(String.valueOf("Total Amount : " +totalAmtData));

            }
        });


    }
}
```

When i try to calculate interest of a long amount. It closes the current activity and sometimes crashes the app. Here is the crash report that i get.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "897667979494"
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:618)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
at com.example.minti.InterestCalculator$1.onClick(InterestCalculator.java:41)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7167)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7140)
at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:813)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27597)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7509)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
```

Comment: If it crashes, it also prints errors on LogCat, and you should post them.

Comment: Hi, thanks chrylis i just edited the question and shared the crash report. Please look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number 897667979494 is too large to fit into an `int`. Use `long` or (usually better with money) `BigDecimal`.

Comment: How to parse BigDecimal instead of `Integer.parseInteger` ?

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Usually `new BigDecimal(stringValue)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
showResult.setText(String.valueOf("Interest : " +showResultData));
```

to

```
showResult.setText("Interest : " + String.valueOf(showResultData));
```

And can you show the error when your application crashed?

Comment: Hi, Checked your code, this is not solving the problem and i just edited the question and added the crash report. Please check

Comment: The maximum value for **int** in Java is 2147483647, you can use **long** (9,223,372,036,854,755,807) for a large value

Comment: So what should i use instead of "integer" so i can calculate any amount without limit ?

Comment: Kasalwe, Can you please provide some code on how to use, please ? Thanks.

Comment: All variable types have limits. You can only change the extent of the limit. Use **long** for int or **double** if you want to support decimals

Comment: Change _int firstValueData, secondValueData, thirdValueData;_ to **long firstValueData, secondValueData, thirdValueData;**. And instead of _Integer.parseInt(...)_, use **Long.parseLong(...)**